# Set bootstrap selected option with ajax value

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I try to display data on the bootstrap select option with ajax, but after I run the data do not want to appear what is wrong?

```
function get_value() {
    $id = 5;
    $q = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('tbl_v')
                      ->where('id', $id)
                      ->order_by('id', 'ASC')
                      ->get();

    $result = $q->result();
    echo json_encode($result );


}   

$(".change").change(function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    if(value>0){
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url+"get_value",  
            type:"POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,               
            data:{id:value},
            success: function(respond){
                $(".get-change").html(respond).selectpicker('refresh');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: try to view the value with this code Alert(JSON.Stringify($(this).val())).

Comment: And don't forget to `json_encode()` your `$q->result()`

Comment: Sorry i am update my question,

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function OnChangeValue()
{
    var pdrp = document.getElementById("yourControlIDHere");
    getvalue= pdrp.options[pdrp.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(getvalue);
}
```

The `Control`

```
<select id="yourControlIDHere" onchange="OnChangeValue(this)" name="companyname" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: I know you are using php but it is a little bit similar.

Comment: thanks however I am making a dynamic select option when I select the select option before

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Code

```
$(".change").change(function(){
var value=$(this).val();
if(value>0){
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"get_value",  
        type:"POST",
        cache: false,               
        data:{id:value},
        success: function(respond){
            $(".get-change").html(respond);
        }
    })
}
});
```

Modal Code:

```
function get_records() {
    $id = 5;
    $q = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('tbl_v')
                      ->where('id', $id)
                      ->order_by('id', 'ASC')
                      ->get();

    $result = $q->result();
}
```

Controller Code:

```
function get_value(){
   $ido = $this->input->post('id');
   $data = $this->your-model-name->get_records($ido);
   $option = "";
   foreach($data as $row){
      $option .= "<option value='".$value['ID']."'>".$row[0]->name."</option>";
   }
   echo $option;
}
```

You need not have to use JSON encoding. Records will be directly appended to the select box. Hope this can help you.

Comment: thank you for the answer, actually already appear but there are constraints when I use bootstrap plugin selecpicker list does not appear,

Comment: Can you give me more details? What constraints are you talking about?

Comment: Do you want to put any conditions in the query?

Comment: so I made a dynamic select option with bootstrap, previously it was already run using `class="form-control"` but when I use jquery plugins bootstrap-select `class="selecpicker"` data does not show.

Comment: What problem do you have in using a select box with `form-control`? Is there any special functionality in it? I was just googling about your problem. I found it is just a class difference. Both are bootstrap select boxes. Can you tell me for what purpose you are using??